# Clone an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
let obj = {
  a : [
    {
      name : 'op'
    }]
};
```

I want to clone it. I used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`. But this does not scale well for huge data when used again and again. Is there any other way to shallow copy the object?

Comment: @Lars that would depend if the OP wants to deep clone or not. The last sentence suggests otherwise

Comment: Oh.. thats odd.. OP is doing  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()` which suggests deep clone..Which are you asking?

Comment: sorry deep clone